# Deduce type in lambda parameter in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a container which stores iterators to other containers as follows:

```
typedef int my_id;    //id
typedef std::set<my_id>  my_group_t;   //group containing ids
typedef typename  my_group_t::iterator  my_group_it_t;    //group iterator

std::pair < my_group_it_t, my_group_it_t >  pair_it_t;  //pair (generally begin,end)
typedef std::vector<  pair_it_t >  my_group_container_t;


my_group_container_t   my_group_container; // (FILL the Container and group with some values)
//print the values using lambdas

auto x = my_group_container.begin();   
auto y = my_group_container.end();

//x is iterator to the vector, similarly y. 

//note that x and y when dereferenced give the pairs of iterators
std::for_each (x, y, [](**xxxx**   pair) -> void {

          auto xx = x.first;    //get first iterator pair
          auto yy = x.second;  //get second iterator pair

      }
```

What should be the type of pair ? `xxxx`. I know lambdas cannot be templated in C++11, but I am not sure how to use `decltype` here.

```
 //I can do this:
  for (; x!=y; ++x) {
    auto xx = x->first;
    auto yy = x->second;
    std::copy(xx,yy,std::ostream_itearator<..> (std::cout, "\n");
  }
```

Note that while the example uses concrete types, my actual use case is in template code, where the real types are not known.

Comment: in above example i can guess the type. but if the container is returned from some other class, I know it is a pair. but not its underlying type. and lambdas cannot take templates

Comment: My first guess would be something like `my_group_container_t::value_type` perhaps?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a little bit based on your comments. If you don't like the edit, feel free to improve it or roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be generic, you have several options:

1. Use iterator traits on the type of `x`:

   ```
   std::for_each(x, y, [](std::iterator_traits<decltype(x)>::value_type pair) { ... })
   ```
2. Use the return type of `*x`:

   ```
   std::for_each(x, y, [](decltype(*x) pair) { ... })
   ```
3. Use the value type of the container (directly or deduced):

   ```
   std::for_each(x, y, [](my_group_container_t::value_type pair) { ... })
   std::for_each(x, y, [](decltype(my_group_container)::value_type pair) { ... })
   ```
4. In case you actually know the type (as in the example), you of course use it directly:

   ```
   std::for_each(x, y, [](pair_it_t pair) { ... })
   ```

In all the cases, you can decorate the type of `pair` with `const` and/or `&` as applicable. Note that in case 2, the type may very well be a reference already - forward (or better) operators are required to return actual references.

Comment: awesome. i kind of forgot iterator_traits :-/ thanks for the answers.

Comment: Also, you can typedef/using the type prior to the line to give it a name, nd reduce noise on an already complex line.

Answer (score 2):

In the provided example, it is `pair_it_t`.

but from template, you can use `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` to retrieve the type.